# Blosc import error into python

Tags: python, c++, linux, c++11, anaconda

I just installed anaconda from a clean install and installed blosc using pip install blosc.  I am now having this import error:

```
In [1]: import blosc
      ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call     last)
<ipython-input-1-d9d5f9fbfb2e>     in <module>()
----> 1 import blosc

/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blosc/__init__.py in <module>()
 11 
 12 # Blosc C symbols that we want to export
---> 13 from blosc.blosc_extension import (
 14     BLOSC_VERSION_STRING as VERSION_STRING,
 15     BLOSC_VERSION_DATE as VERSION_DATE,

ImportError: /usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blosc/blosc_extension.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE9_M_appendEPKcm
```

I am running Linux Mint 18 Sarah 64-bit
Kernel Linux 4.4.0-21-generic x86_64
MATE 1.14.1

Can anyone please help with this error?  Thank you.

Comment: it is because blosc is not installed properly or it is dependent on other module. Just check for that first

Comment: which module is it dependent on

Comment: blosc ships with  c sources

Answer (score 0):

On conda, the blosc package is the 'c' package of blosc. In order to install python bindings please use the package 'python-blosc' instead.

Also, check the installation instructions that were updated today at:

https://github.com/Blosc/python-blosc#installing